# How to make \verbatim more condensed?

Tags: verbatim

This is what I'm doing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
\verbatim
Hello, world!
\endverbatim
\end{document}
```

I need this text to have a bit smaller distance between letters than usual (by 10%).

Comment: Please make your code fragment as compilable small document.

Comment: @Zarko done, thanks for noticing

Comment: While the legibility of the `cmtt` font probably wouldn't suffer from compressing the interletter space, that wouldn't necessarily be true for other monospace fonts.  Would compression of the glyphs themselves be acceptable?  (If only letterspacing is wanted, the `soul` package might accept negative values; not checked.)

Comment: can't you just use `\small` rather than horizontally compressing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `\lsstyle` from the `microtype` package, and adjust the `letterspacing` option to a negative quantity that gives the desired result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[letterspace=-100]{microtype}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
Hello, world!
\end{verbatim}
\lsstyle
\begin{verbatim}
Hello, world!
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the space between letters to be reduced in all `verbatim` environments, you could use something like

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{verbatim}{\lsstyle}
```

so the `\lsstyle` would be applied automatically to any `verbatim` environment.